# How to post JSON data using curl?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send JSON data using curl, but it does not get posted.

```
$data = array("name" => " Hagrid", "age" => "36");
$content= json_encode($data,true);
$url ='http://www.example.com/webervices/msg.php';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
print_r($status);
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

And in `msg.php`

```
print_r($_POST);
```

But it prints a blank array.

It would be helpful if someone has any solution which posts JSON data using php.

Comment: Do you figure it out how to do this yet ? I came to the same problem like you now = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309035/post-json-data-using-curl-php. I was wondering if can answer it - if you know the answer to it. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `msg.php` script you need to do this to get the json content:

```
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
print $body;
```

Comment: Its working for all data but it not working when sending image file, $body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
print $body;  Its give blank value.  What should i do for sending image file using json and curl.